# How to set cell style in ag-Grid while processing nodes?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

ag-Grid provides a mechanism using the cellStyle to modify the style of a cell.

However, I want to change the color of a cell while processing nodes. I know the exact node which I want to change the color of.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: I decided to store the values that had been changed in an array and in the cellStyle function, check if the cells value was in the array and color it appropriately. Not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a cell rendering function:

```
// put the value in bold
colDef.cellRenderer = function(params) {
    return '<b>' + params.value.toUpperCase() + '</b>';
}
```

You can apply the style depending on the value of the node - this will be made available in the params argument

Comment: I needed to do something like node.cell.cellStyle = {border: '1px solid red', 'text-align' : 'center'};

Answer (score 0):

Use cellStyle or cellClass or cellClass in column property and return the

```
 var colDef = {name: 'Dynamic Styles', field' 'field2', cellStyle: cellStyling}

function cellStyling(params){
    if(true){
        return {'background-color':''};
    } else {
        return {'color': '#9B9999' ,'background-color':'#E8E2E1'};
    }
 }
```

as per your comment, code can be use like--

```
 $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function(node){
    for(var j=0;j<node.gridOptionsWrapper.columnController.allDisplayedColumns.length;j++){
    if(node.gridOptionsWrapper.columnController.allDisplayedColumns[j].colDef.headerName==="column Name"){
            node.gridOptionsWrapper.columnController.allDisplayedColumns[j].colDef.cellStyle = {apply style};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I needed to do something like node.cell.cellStyle = {border: '1px solid red', 'text-align' : 'center'};