# AG grid dynamic color value for cellstyle

Tags: angular, ag-grid

```
Ag grid column definition


 columnDefs = [
                    { headerName: "Status", field: "statusCode", cellStyle: {'background-color': 'green'}}, }

                ]
```

Instead of  hard coding color, its getting from server.

```
columnDefs = [
            {  headerName: "Status", field: "statusCode", cellStyle: {'background-color': ['colorVal']}}, }

        ]
```

**colorVal** will have value like red or green, but the above syntax is not working.

This is the json that I'm setting to the rowData of ag-grid.

```
 {"statusCode":101,"colorVal":green}
```

Can I set using or use this.gridOptions. 
?

Comment: you are setting color in html part in controller side ?

Comment: controller side, in typescript

Comment: try this `let data=  {"statusCode":101,"colorVal":green}` and than `{  headerName: "Status", field: "statusCode", cellStyle: {'background-color':data.colorVal}}, }`
`

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'data'.
any

Comment: can I call a method there and set ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370574/how-to-set-cell-style-in-ag-grid-while-processing-nodes/41378010#41378010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Basavaraj Thanks for the hint.

```
columnDefs = [
                        { headerName: "Status", field: "statusCode",cellStyle: this.cellStyling},

                ]
```

Call this method to display style dynamically

```
cellStyling(params:any){     
       return {'background-color': params.data.colourCode};
  }
```

Comment: is this working for you ?  strange , bcoz you are getting params which you are not sending from anywhere , so how it will work ?

Comment: getRows: (params: any) => { //setting the row data, getting pagination details }

Comment: Very nice... I had a problem where I could not get dynamic colors to work then came across your solution. Worked great for my problem!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146132/dynamic-change-of-cell-color-with-ag-grid/55166909#55166909

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let data= {"statusCode":101,"colorVal":green}

columnDefs = [
        {  headerName: "Status", field: "statusCode", cellStyle: {'background-color': data.colorVal}}, }
    ]
```

here `let` is a local variable you have to use this within the scope of your method

PS:- Too long for comment so posting this as answer.